# an example of stationary markov chain which doesn't satisfy the detailed balance

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

I understand that if a markovian process satisfies the detailed balance relation:$\pi_{i}p_{ij}=\pi_{j}p_{ji}$, then it is stationary. So detailed balance relation  is a sufficient condition. But is is also necessary? If not, could someone give an easy example?

Comment: It is not necessary. For example consider a Markov chain on $\{A,B,C\}$ with $p(A,B) = p(B,C) = p(C,A) = p$ and $p(A,C)=p(C,B)=p(B,A)=1-p$. Then the stationary distribution is always uniform over the 3 states but the detailed balance condition is only satisfied if $p=1/2$. When the detailed balance condition holds, the chain is said to be *reversible* (with respect to its stationary distribution). This is a very strong condition, which basically means that a trajectory and its time reversal have the same distribution (at equilibrium).

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thanks. This is a great example. I like the time reversal idea.